# css float right space

Tags: css, html

anyone know how to fix this! on 'Get In Touch button'
[image]

it works find in another browser except IE7;
HTML:

```
<NAV>
    <UL>
        <LI><a href="#">Home</a></LI>
        <LI><a href="#">Branding</a></LI>
        <LI><a href="#">About</a></LI>
        <LI><a href="#">Get In Touch</a></LI>
    </UL>
</NAV>
```

CSS:

```
nav { float:right;}
nav ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
nav ul li { float:left; }
nav ul li { display:block; background:#ccc; padding:5px; margin-left:5px;}
```

Comment: Fix what? You need to be more specific as to what you see as wrong with the output.

Comment: You want all the buttons to have the same height, so that the 'get in touch' doesn't stick out at the bottom?

Comment: sorry my bad! can you see on "Get In Touch" its not one line

Comment: Also, you **don't need** to set display:block if you already set float:left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to the `nav ul li` CSS rule.

About the white-space property: http://vidasp.net/CSS-white-space-property.html

Answer (score 1):

You may need to explicitly set width on the list and/or nav container.

This is quite common in IE7 and down, where the dumb browser needs to be told there's room allotted for the content.

Answer (score 0):

`nav ul li { display:block; background:#ccc; padding:5px; margin-left:5px; width: auto; }`

Add in that `width: auto;` - see if that helps.

Neuro

Answer (score -3):

use

```
clear: right; float:right;
```

Comment: Please provide explanation on your answer why it solves the problem of OP.  This will help others to see if the solution fits for their problems!